# Carrying CreationContext.AdditionalArguments on Castle Windsor

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor, castle

I need to pass some arguments to a custom AbstractLifestyleManager derived type.

When I request an instance of a type from the container, I use the following overload:

```
T Resolve<T>(string key, object argumentsAsAnonymousType)
```

For example:

```
public IHttpController CreateController(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, string controllerName)
{
    var controller = this.container.Resolve<IHttpController>(
        controllerName,
        new { requestProperties = controllerContext.Request.Properties });

    // ...
}
```

Then, inside the custom AbstractLifestyleManager derived type, I can do this:

```
var messageProperties = (IDictionary<string, object>)
            context.AdditionalArguments["requestProperties"];
```

Which returns the value that I have previsouly passed.

However, if I call `base.Resolve(context, releasePolicy)` the AdditionalArguments is null if the code enters the custom type recursively.

Is it possible to pass/flow the AdditionalArguments between the `base.Resolve` calls?

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure how the flow is, when implementing a lifestyle manager, but it sounds like the problem that CreateContext AdditionalArguments aren't propagated to child context per default. See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854701/resolving-httpcontrollercontext-with-castle-windsor).

If that is the case, you could try to change the default as described in the linked question by subclassing DefaultDependencyResolver.